# JS setTimeout won't wait using Scratchpad

Tags: javascript

Consider the following script

```js
function func()
{
  alert('b');
  if (document.readyState != 'complete')
    setTimeout(func(),1000);
  else
    alert('a');
};

window.location.replace('https://www.google.com/');
setTimeout(func(),5000);
```

When I run the script, I get an alert immediately without waiting 5 seconds.

Comment: by removing the brackets, I don't get the alert containing 'b', that's mean the function func does not go in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets from func:

```
 setTimeout(func,5000);
```

Otherwise the function is called immediately rather than being passed as a function to be called later.

```js
function func()
{
  alert('b');
  if (document.readyState != 'complete')
    setTimeout(func,1000);
  else
    alert('a');
};

setTimeout(func,5000);
```

Comment: now the function is not called immediately, but never.
I don't get the alert('b')

Comment: The `window.location.replace` line breaks the code here, see my edit.

Comment: what is the solution to this type of problem ?